# Getting {{count}} with time_ago_in_words

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have this code in my application:

```
  def comment_poster(comment)
    if comment.user
      "posted by #{comment.user.username} #{time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)} ago"
    else
      "posted by anonymous"
    end
  end
```

However, this works only when I have posted in seconds ago, and years ago:

```
posted by teejay about 1 year ago
posted by teejay about 1 month ago
```

When I edit the created_at value to a few days ago it gives me this:

```
posted by thorpe {{count}} days ago
```

What should I do for this to make it work and lose that `{{count}}`

Edit: I am using Rails 2.3.5 if that means anything

Edit: #2

I fixed the problem by pasting [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623762/rails-time-ago-in-words-producing-bad-output/4624098#4624098) at `config/locales/en.yml`

```
  datetime:
     distance_in_words:
       half_a_minute: "half a minute"
       less_than_x_seconds:
         one:   "less than 1 second"
         other: "less than %{count} seconds"
       x_seconds:
         one:   "1 second"
         other: "%{count} seconds"
       less_than_x_minutes:
         one:   "less than a minute"
         other: "less than %{count} minutes"
       x_minutes:
         one:   "1 minute"
         other: "%{count} minutes"
       about_x_hours:
         one:   "about 1 hour"
         other: "about %{count} hours"
       x_days:
         one:   "1 day"
         other: "%{count} days"
       about_x_months:
         one:   "about 1 month"
         other: "about %{count} months"
       x_months:
         one:   "1 month"
         other: "%{count} months"
       about_x_years:
         one:   "about 1 year"
         other: "about %{count} years"
       over_x_years:
         one:   "over 1 year"
         other: "over %{count} years"
       almost_x_years:
         one:   "almost 1 year"
         other: "almost %{count} years"
     prompts:
       year:   "Year"
       month:  "Month"
       day:    "Day"
       hour:   "Hour"
       minute: "Minute"
       second: "Seconds"
```

Can anyone explain what the issue was?

Comment: Your code should work - have you made any changes to ActionPack in actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb ?

Comment: I haven't. I don't even know how.

Comment: That code uses the new way of accessing the variables in the i18n gem. With the %{variable} instead of {{variable}}. Just so you know why it solved your problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with the i18n gem version. If you downgrade to 0.4.1 this problem will disappear.

The thing is that from version 0.4.1 on, the way of accessing variables isn't {{variable}} anymore.

Comment: How is it that rails doesn't accommodate this? Seems odd to have to downgrade a gem for something like this.. (this worked for me as well, thanks :))

Comment: the 0.4.1 might not get installed from the original gems source. so add gemcutter.org as a source and remove all other versions.